# Grails audit logging plugin

Tags: grails, logging, audit

I am trying to store an instance or at least id of each domain that is auditable. For example, there is a domain 'Student' and is auditable. So, whenever the domain an instance of domain is created or edited, a new record is stored in audit log. What I want is to store the id of each domain that is saved or updated. How can it be done ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grails Envers plugin that uses Hibernate Envers underneath. Plugin information can be found on plugins site [here](http://grails.org/plugin/envers).

Answer (score 1):

You can better refer to the url: http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging

The above plugin works well for the domain class without collection, in case if you using collections in domain class, refer this stackoverflow link: [How to determine Collection changes in a Hibernate PostUpdateEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812364/how-to-determine-collection-changes-in-a-hibernate-postupdateeventlistener)

Hope it will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

I Wouldn't use the audit plugin , it has some issues when running your tests. This plugin in was created when the GORM didn't provide support for events. You can intercept the following events

```
beforeInsert - Executed before an object is initially persisted to the database
beforeUpdate - Executed before an object is updated
beforeDelete - Executed before an object is deleted
beforeValidate - Executed before an object is validated
afterInsert - Executed after an object is persisted to the database
afterUpdate - Executed after an object has been updated
afterDelete - Executed after an object has been deleted
onLoad - Executed when an object is loaded from the database
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Its an old project and audit logging is already used, I cannot change that. Is there any way to use beforeInsert in audit loging plugin domain ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use events with AuditLog plugin like below and then add what ever you would like too. Hope this makes sense

```
def onChange = { oldMap,newMap ->
        println "Person was changed ..."
        oldMap.each({ key, oldVal ->
            if(oldVal != newMap[key]) {
                println " * $key changed from $oldVal to " + newMap[key]
            }
        })
    }


def onSave = {
        println "new datainserted"
        // may optionally refer to newState map
    }
```

In any of these methods we can use

```
 def event = new AuditLogEvent(
                    actor: actor,
                    className: className,
                    eventName: eventName,
                    persistedObjectId: objectId,
                    propertyName: propertyName,
                    newValue: newValue
            )
            if (event.validate()) {
                auditLogListener.saveAuditLog(event)
                log.info "Logged audit event [$event]"
            }
```