# Get old values in collection at onPostUpdateCollection event in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate 4.2 for persistent storage. I am implementing hibernate event listeners for getting the notification when particular object is modified. 
Tried Implementing `PostUpdateEventListener` event in hibernate but it does not trigger method at the time of updating collection values.
Currently implementing `PostCollectionUpdateEventListener` which triggers method when collection is updated.

The class is as follows

```
public class Employee {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private Set<Address> addresses;

  //all getters and setters are implemented.
}

public class Address {
  private int id;
  private String street;
  private String city;

  //all getters and setters are implemented.
}
```

I have implemented mapping as xml files with all mapping and following set mapping

In Employee.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Employee">
  ... all mappings
  <set name="addresses" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="Emp_id"/>
    <one-to-many class="Address"/>
  </set>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Address .hbm.xml file is implemented correctly.

In hibernate event listener

```
public void onPostUpdateCollection(PostCollectionUpdateEvent event) {
  Object obj = event.getAffectedOwnerOrNull();
  //this gives me updated values.

  I want now code to get old collection values which going to be deleted.
}
```

I have tried the following line

```
PersistentCollection collection = event.getCollection();
// this gives new update collection values of addresses
```

I have seen method in PersistentCollection `Serializable getStoredSnapshot()` but it gives empty values.

In any way if i can get the old collection values then please help me.
I am inserting new value of addresses so that it triggers `onPostUpdateCollection()` event method on Employee class object.

My Question is :
How can i retrieve old values of collection?
Trying to get old values from couple of days, any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PostCollectionUpdateEventListener there is no way to get old collection values.
I used PreCollectionUpdateEventListener class to get old collection values as follows

```
public void onPreUpdateCollection(PreCollectionUpdateEvent event) {
  PersistentCollection collection = event.getCollection();
  HashMap snapshot = (HashMap) collection.getStoredSnapshot();
  //set values are also stored as map values with same key and value as set value
  Set<Map.Entry> set = snapshot.entrySet();
  //Now this set contains key value of old collection values before update
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the old objects from the `PostCollectionUpdateEvent`, we need to access the `CollectionUpdateAction` class.

I'm using hibernate version is 5.1.3.Final. First, Create a new class which contains `oldObj` reference by extending the PostCollectionUpdateEvent.

```
package org.hibernate.event.spi;

import org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentCollection;
import org.hibernate.persister.collection.CollectionPersister;

public class MyPostCollectionUpdateEvent extends PostCollectionUpdateEvent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Object oldObj;

    public MyPostCollectionUpdateEvent(Object oldObj, CollectionPersister collectionPersister, PersistentCollection collection, EventSource source) {
        super(collectionPersister, collection, source);
        this.oldObj = oldObj;
    }

    public Object getOldObj() {
        return oldObj;
    }

    public void setOldObj(Object oldObj) {
        this.oldObj = oldObj;
    }
}
```

`CollectionUpdateAction` is a final class, so one can't extend it. To overcome that, create a package `org.hibernate.action.internal` in your project and copy the [CollectionUpdateAction](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/action/internal/CollectionUpdateAction.java) class from hibernate-orm in to your project, Then edit the class, to set the old object reference.

```
public class CollectionUpdateAction extends CollectionAction {

    private final boolean emptySnapshot;
    private Object oldObject;

    /**
     * Constructs a CollectionUpdateAction
     *
     * @param collection The collection to update
     * @param persister The collection persister
     * @param id The collection key
     * @param emptySnapshot Indicates if the snapshot is empty
     * @param session The session
     */
    public CollectionUpdateAction(
            final PersistentCollection collection,
            final CollectionPersister persister,
            final Serializable id,
            final boolean emptySnapshot,
            final SessionImplementor session) {
        super( persister, collection, id, session );
        this.emptySnapshot = emptySnapshot;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() throws HibernateException {
        final Serializable id = getKey();
        final SessionImplementor session = getSession();
        final CollectionPersister persister = getPersister();
        final PersistentCollection collection = getCollection();
        final boolean affectedByFilters = persister.isAffectedByEnabledFilters( session );

        preUpdate();
        this.oldObject = session.getPersistenceContext().getSnapshot(collection);
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }


    private void postUpdate() {
        final EventListenerGroup<PostCollectionUpdateEventListener> listenerGroup = listenerGroup( EventType.POST_COLLECTION_UPDATE );
        if ( listenerGroup.isEmpty() ) {
            return;
        }
        final MyPostCollectionUpdateEvent event = new MyPostCollectionUpdateEvent(
                oldObject,
                getPersister(),
                getCollection(),
                eventSource()
        );
        for ( PostCollectionUpdateEventListener listener : listenerGroup.listeners() ) {
            listener.onPostUpdateCollection( event );
        }
    }

}
```

Make sure that your classes are given higher priority than hibernate jar in your classpath. Then, only this solution will work and you can get the old objects reference in your listener class,

```
public class DummyCollectionEventListener implements PostCollectionUpdateEventListener { 

    @Override
    public void onPostUpdateCollection(PostCollectionUpdateEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof MyPostCollectionUpdateEvent) {

            Object oldObjects = ((MyPostCollectionUpdateEvent) event).getOldObj();
            PersistentCollection persistentCollection = event.getCollection();

            String role = persistentCollection.getRole();
            String propertyName = role.substring(role.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, role.length());
            System.out.println("property name : " + propertyName);

            if (persistentCollection instanceof PersistentList && oldObjects instanceof List) {
                System.out.println("Old Object List : " + ((List<?>) oldObjects));
            } else if (oldObjects instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
                Map<?, ?> props = (Map<?, ?>) oldObjects;
                if (persistentCollection instanceof PersistentMap)
                    System.out.println("Old Object Map : " + props);
                else if (persistentCollection instanceof PersistentSet)
                    System.out.println("Old Object Set : " + props.keySet());
                else
                    System.out.println("Unknown Class type : " + persistentCollection.getClass());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unknown event");
            }
        }
    }
}
```